# Is there a way to add additional behavior to jquery's $.ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is the following.
We have lots of ajax call via $.ajax function. Now I would like to add some loader indicator that will show up when ajax call started and disappear when ajax call finishes. 
Is there a way to extend jquery's $.ajax function with this kind of behavior.

Of course it is always possible to search for all $.ajax in code and add necessary behavior but I feel somehow lazy to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have jQuery functions for that. Take this example:

```
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

Now the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $().ajaxStart(function() { $('#loading').show(); });
  $().ajaxStop(function() { $('#loading').hide(); });

});
```

ajaxStart detects that an ajax call is being made and executes a function. ajaxStop will detect that the ajax call has ended and will execute a function. This works with any ajax call in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You use `ajaxStart`/`ajaxStop`. may find [this article](http://skfox.com/2008/04/28/jquery-example-ajax-activity-indicator/) to be of help.